# Ubuntu 20.04 VM on VirtualBox incompatible with "hardinfo" app

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, device-manager, ubuntu-20.04

I already asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446471/ubuntu-20-04-vm-on-virtualbox-incompatible-with-hardinfo-app) Q on "Ask Ubuntu", but I think "Super User" community might help me too here.

Question:
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 VM on Oracle VirtualBox 7.0 (from Win10 host OS), and would like to see the HW elements via some GUI app (not from command line). From this Q:
[Does Ubuntu have a "device manager" equivalent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887264/does-ubuntu-have-a-device-manager-equivalent-and-what-is-an-easy-way-to-acces)

I understood what the best option is "hardinfo" app (System Profiler and Benchmark).

Unfortunately, after installing (both via command line and via Ubuntu Software App) it looks like the **hardinfo app has some graphic issues/incompatibility** (snapshot below)

I'd very appreciate the tip how to overcome this issue, since I'm very interesting to get HW info in the GUI manner.

Note: I haven't any issue with other GUI apps

Snapshot:
[image]

Hardinfo app version:
[image]

Full version of Ubuntu and Gnome:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Box (and other virtual Apps like VMware) provide hardware emulation in the VM for various hardware items including graphics hardware.

So if System Profiler and Benchmark does not work with the emulated hardware, then you cannot use it in the Virtual Machine.  It is limited to real machines.

Comment: But isn't this "hardinfo" app is just a graphical representation of text which returns from misc CLI commands, like "lshw"?  If VirtualBox hypervisor didn't emulate HW, commands like "lshw" should return some empty lists of HW, and I'd expect what "Hardinfo" itself should represent empty HW, but its graphic itself should work OK (at list title of window)?

Comment: I think the app needs the real Device Manager from a real machine.  A VM just has emulated hardware so that is why it is not working. VBOX is not a bare metal hypervisor as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

This open-source project is housed on Github at
[lpereira / hardinfo](https://github.com/lpereira/hardinfo).

I understand that the project was abandoned by its maintainer, so is now
in the hands of volunteers.

The version you got from your repository might be older than the one on
Github. I suggest to download and compile the project from source.
Detailed instructions are to be found on Github.